# spark scala avoid shuffling after RowMatix calculation

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, partitioning

scala spark : How to avoid RDD shuffling in join after Distributed Matrix operation

1. created a dense matrix as a input to calculate cosine distance between columns

   `val rowMarixIn = sc.textFile("input.csv").map{ line =>
   val values = line.split(" ").map(_.toDouble)
   Vectors.dense(values)
   }`
2. Extracted set of entries from co-ordinated matrix after the cosine calculations

   ```
   val coMarix = new RowMatrix(rowMarixIn)
   val similerRows = coMatrix.columnSimilarities()

   //extract entires over a specific Threshold

   val rowIndices = similerRows.entries.map {case MatrixEntry(row: Long, col: Long, sim: Double) =>
   if (sim > someTreshold )){
   col,sim
   }`
   ```
3. We have a another RDD with rdd2(key,Val2)

just want to join the two rdd's,  rowIndices(key,Val) , rdd2(key,Val2)

`val joinedRDD = rowIndices.join(rdd2)`

this will result in a shuffle , 
What are best practices to follow in order to avoid shuffle or any suggestion on a better approach is much appreciated

Comment: If you need to do a join, you will have to endure that shuffle. In normal cases you can reduce the time taken by shuffle by using a consistant partitioner like `HashPartitioner`. But here since your first RDD is being computed you will need a reshuffle even to use a consistent partitioner.

Comment: Thanks , i was trying to think of adopting  'pre-partitioning' as discussed here would help , http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/matei-zaharia-amp-camp-2012-advanced-spark.pdf 
since we are doing a matrix calculation wanted see if its possible to keep track of the partitions before and after that

Comment: One thing to be skeptical about - That pdf is from 2012...

Comment: yeah that's why i wanted getting some input from the community i'm on 1.6.2 atm

Comment: I think you should ask this on Spark user mailing list -> user@spark.apache.org

Comment: thanks will do that

Comment: Pre-partitioning doesn't avoid shuffle. It just puts it in a different place.